# Не подключается демон docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

```
systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-18 10:57:17 UTC; 11min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 26563 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26563 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 713ms

июл 18 10:57:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
июл 18 10:57:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
июл 18 10:57:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.




-- Начат процесс запуска юнита docker.socket.
    июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Запуск юнита docker.socket завершен
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Процесс запуска юнита docker.socket был завершен.
--
-- Результат: done.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита docker.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
июл 18 10:57:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.





 journalctl -u docker --since=-1h
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 17:16:42 UTC, end at Sat 2020-07-18 11:19:31 UTC. --
июл 18 10:23:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
июл 18 10:23:15 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:15.693965256Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=777
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" module=containerd revision=773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containe
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." module=containerd type=io.contai
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." module=containerd type=io.co
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/conta
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." module=containerd type=io.container
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." module=containerd type=io.containe
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grp
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.g
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." module=containerd type=io.contain
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.g
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.g
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." module=containerd type=io.containe
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." module=containerd type=io.container
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." module=containerd type=io.containe
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.gr
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." module=containerd type=io.conta
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" module="cont
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" module="containerd
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.039082s" module=containerd
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.625040933Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.833872860Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.834417235Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.834550151Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.834603276Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.834668849Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.834717391Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.835164005Z" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.836709943Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.844851089Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 237217da1b687d1b2b24f43757c6affe92db62e3542051
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.849247235Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 5d3c137eb4f5e771964a3562ac6f07a2bad23fb19737fd
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.853777599Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 743cd0747adb189848d73b94ece8225a2f3cfa7df91a26
июл 18 10:23:16 raspberrypi dockerd[665]: time="2020-07-18T10:23:16.857842807Z" level=error msg="Failed to load container mount 8ec5b96587c26c333da022e772c6238ab9217ba406a17c
lines 1-42
```

помогите пожалуйста, не запускается демон докера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогли эти команды

```
ip link add name docker0 type bridge
ip addr add dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
```

Comment: От "не запускается" не поможет, а от "не подключается" вполне.

Comment: @Hellseher исправил